# Внутри функции не обновляется состояние

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
/* global ymaps */
import React from "react";
import Map from '../../../Map';


 class Ciomponent extends React.Component {
     state = {q: false}


drawingData = (mapThis, opt) => {
    console.log(this)
}

render() {


    return (
            <React.Fragment>
               <div onClick={() => {this.seState({q: true})}}/>
               <Map drawingData = {this.drawingData.bind(this)}/>
            </React.Fragment>
    )
}}



 export default Ciomponent;
```

Я меняю состояние по клику на div, в react devTools оно меняется, но при вызове функции drawingData в консоль выводится первоначальное состояние, хотя она давно уже поменялось.
Почему такое может происходить?

Comment: зачем вы используете стрелочную функцию и делаете `.bind(this)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/adoring-booth-14zcb)**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    q: false
  };

  drawingData = (mapThis, opt) => {
    console.log(this);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={() => this.setState({ q: true })}>Click to change the state</div>
        <div onClick={this.drawingData}>Click after change the state</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```